# I have oil in the coolant of my Suburban what is the cause?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, suburban

I have a 2002 Chevrolet Suburban with a 350 engine it has oil in the coolant.

What is the cause?

It has over 200000 miles.

Comment: Voted to close. Has to be a decent head gasket question around here, if not we need one